# Need to convert the filter style applied to an image to specific JSON format

Tags: javascript

Need to convert the filter style applied to an image to specific JSON format to store in database.

Wrote a method to do that but got stuck in the middle.

```
<img src="image1.jpg" class="img-responsive"  style="-webkit-filter: brightness(161%) contrast(62%) invert(27%) saturate(193%);">//Filters will be in same order
```

Need to create JSON format like {"brightness":"161","contrast":"62","invert":"27","saturate":"193"}

I tried :

```
var style= "-webkit-filter: brightness(161%) contrast(62%) invert(27%) saturate(193%)";
alert(JSON.stringify(crtJson(style)));
function crtJson(paramString){
        var paramArray = (paramString.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''));

        return paramArray;//comes like 1616227193 [no clue how to split.Got stuck]
    }
```

Js fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xd1eaLfk/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...try this...

```
var style= "-webkit-filter: brightness(161%) contrast(62%) invert(27%) saturate(193%)";
console.log(JSON.stringify(crtJson(style)));
alert(JSON.stringify(crtJson(style)));

function crtJson(paramString){
                var paramArray = (((paramString.replace(/[^\d%]/g, '')).replace(/[^\d]/g,',')).slice(0,-1)).split(',');
                var paramJson={};
                paramJson.brightness = paramArray[0];
                paramJson.contrast = paramArray[1];
                paramJson.invert = paramArray[2];
                paramJson.saturate = paramArray[3];
                return paramJson;
            }
```

*Note : If the filters are shuffled then output JSON value too will be jumbled...*

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Nofiden/aL9cgmq5/5/)

Answer (score 0):

It works even if filters are shuffled.

Here is your code with match() method and capturing parentheses:

```
var style= "-webkit-filter: brightness(161%) contrast(62%) invert(27%) saturate(193%)";
alert(JSON.stringify(crtJson(style)));
function crtJson(paramString){
    var paramArray = {};
    var regexp = /([a-zA-Z]+)\(([0-9]+)%\)/g;
    var array = regexp.exec(paramString);
    while(array != null)
    {
        paramArray[array[1]] = array[2];
        array = regexp.exec(paramString);
    }

    return paramArray;
}
```